# .PY to .EXE using Pyinstaller and including Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to convert my python module to exe file.
When I tried to convert using Pyinstaller, it did not included Selenium and Chromedriver.exe
Could anyone help me with converting .py to .exe with all dependencies like selenium.

Below is my sample representation of code.
**Note** Assumption is I will share required version of Chromedriver with Zip file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

def get_webpage(url):
    #This block will get the requested website
    url = url
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    input('Thank you for using the Automation')
    return driver

def main():
    url = str(input('please enter the required url : '))
    drive = get_webpage(url)
    sleep(10)
    print('Closing the function')
    sleep(3)
    
main()
```

When I tried to run .exe file of this,
It gave me below error.
Traceback :
File 'Exe_try_v2.0.py', line 11, in 
ModuleNotFoundError : no module named 'selenuim'
[9252] failed to execute script Exe_try_v2.0

Comment: The installer should install dependencies using pip

Comment: Can you please share more information. When I tried using the time module it worked.
But when I added the selenium, it failed. Do we need to give any separate command while converting from .py to .exe ?